# What is the best way to store a file in application, database of filesystem?

Tags: database, file-storage

I am curently developping a java/jee app in which i need to store files.I tried storing files as blob in the DB but i got a problem in size of files which must be configured in the application server so i am thinking about storing those files directly in the server disk.So i want to know what is better storing files as blob or directly in the disk.

Comment: db is a bad place. disk only works if you only ever have one instance of the application running on the very same server / disk. Just store the files on a file server or in the cloud, e.g. S3

Comment: @luk2302 why is db a bad place?

Comment: it will take up space on the db server, thus you will need larger machine. Also, db will be spending huge amounts in I/O while storing and retrieveing the file. There is a nice link which explains pros and conds of both approaches : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150669/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-store-large-files-10-mb-in-a-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is to only store **path of the files** in the database and be sure to correctly handle deletions or modifications to avoid orphaned files.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad practice to store file in db.

But instead of that, you can store the file in server disk and map the file path in db. This will be good.